# Cannot implement user roles in next-auth, 'user' does not have identical modifiers

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to implement user roles in next-auth.  On my DB, I have a prisma enum `UserRole` set to 'ADMIN`and`USER`.  In my **auth.ts** file I added role to the session object and I am receiving the following error:

```
All declarations of 'user' must have identical modifiers.ts(2687)
⚠ Error(TS2687)  |  

All declarations of user must have identical modifiers.
(property) Session.user?: {
    id: string;
    role: UserRole;
    email?: string | null | undefined;
    image?: string | null | undefined;
    name?: string | null | undefined;
} & {
    id: string;
    role: UserRole;
    email?: string | null | undefined;
    image?: string | null | undefined;
    name?: string | null | undefined;
}
```

When I log out my session on the front end the session with user role comes through as expected.  I tried to make a next-auth.d.ts file with the following based on another post I found on SO:

```
import type { UserRole } from "@prisma/client";
import type { DefaultUser } from "next-auth";
declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user?: DefaultUser & {
      id: string;
      role: UserRole;
      name?: string | null | undefined;
      email?: string | null | undefined;
      image?: string | null | undefined;
    };
  }

  interface User extends DefaultUser {
    id: string;
    role: UserRole;
    name?: string | null | undefined;
    email?: string | null | undefined;
    image?: string | null | undefined;
  }
}
```

and here is my auth.ts file where the error is occuring:

```
declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: {
      id: string;
      // ...other properties
      role: UserRole;
      email?: string | null | undefined;
      image?: string | null | undefined;
      name?: string | null | undefined;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }

 export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = user.id;

        session.user.role = user.role;
        session.user.email = user.email;
        session.user.image = user.image;
        session.user.name = user.name;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
```

I am not sure what I am missing here to get the error to go away.  If the code I posted isn't sufficient to see what is going on, I have the project here:  https://github.com/sjohnston82/quarter-master2

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript the following modifiers are known:

- `public`
- `protected`
- `private`
- `readonly`

Read more here: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/data-modifiers

The error message warns you that you have several declarations of `user` and they contradict each-other in their access modifier. A rule of thumb about access modifiers is that they are what you specify and, if you do not specify an access modifier for a resource, then everything in a `class` is `public` by default and everything in a `module` is `private` by default, except you are using the `export` keyword for it.

In order to fix your issue, you will need to keep the above in mind and revisit all the declarations of `user` in place and make sure they are compatible in terms of their access modifier.